# Decode Nested Dictionaries in Plist

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, plist

I have a plist as in screenshot. It fullfills tables and Its cells. I want to get all dictionaries inside "Admin", for example, "FirstTable" "SecondTable" etc.. Below code gives

> "Type '(key: Any, value: Any)' doesnot conform to protocol 'Sequence'

error.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Admin", ofType: "plist") {
           myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
           let admin = myDict?.object(forKey: "Admin") as! NSDictionary
           for dicts in admin{
               for sub_dict in dicts{
                   print(sub_dict)
               }
           }
}
```

[image: Plist Screenshot]

Comment: Why do you use only dictionaries? Instead of `cell-1, -2, -3` and `First- , Second-, ThirdTable` arrays are more suitable because unlike a dictionary they have a specific order. And in Swift 4 you can use `PropertyListDecoder` to decode plist directly into a struct.

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed example please? Do I need to change FirstTable to array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate through a dictionary the same way as you iterate through an array.
You will have to change

```
for dicts in admin {
```

to

```
for (key, value) in admin {
```

as a dictionary-entry consists of a key and a value and not just a single object like e.g. an array.

If you want to iterate through all dictionaries you will "need" recursion. If you don't know what that is, it's basically a method that calls itself (but not infinitely).
You could do that for example like this:

```
func iterateThroughDictionary(dict: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    for (key, value) in dict {
        if let subDict = value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            iterateThroughDictionary(dict: subDict)
        } else {
            print(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call it with the root-dictionary.

Comment: With that I can only reach FirstTable, SecondTable etc.. how I can for in cells?  cell-1, cell-2 etc...

Comment: It won't work in my case because for example for thirdtable It has only two string in it so It doesn't have any dictionary in it. In your function, all dictionaries need to have same count of dictionaries I guess..

Comment: No they don't. The function will "open" a dictionary. Then it will iterate through ALL entries in it. If the entry is another dictionary it will then open that one and iterate through all of its entries and so on. This will work with (almost) infinitely nested dictionaries. If an entry is a string however you can then do whatever you want to do with it.